# Scrapy can't grab asp.net datagrid pages if page number > 6

Tags: python, asp.net, datagrid, web-scraping, scrapy

from the start_url, you will find there are 13 pages
but use following code, i can just get 1-6 pages

start_urls = ["http://www.avocatsparis.org/Eannuaire/CMSListeRecherche.aspx?nom=&Pre=&ChReNom=2&Adr=&Arr=8&mail=False&Site=False&Toque=&etranger=False&Spec=41"]

```
def parse(self, response):
    i = 1;
    while i <= 13:
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'__EVENTTARGET':'_ctl0$Corps$DataGridPager1$Page_' + str(i),'__EVENTARGUMENT':''},
                    callback=self.parse_post,
                    dont_click=False)
        i = i + 1


def parse_post(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select("//td[@width='400px']")
    for title in titles:
        link = title.select("a/@href").extract()[0]
        yield Request(urljoin('http://www.avocatsparis.org/Eannuaire/',link), callback=self.parse_details)
```

Comment: I've debugged a bit: passed the page index (`i`) through the `meta` dictionary - your `parse_post` method is called 13 times - it works. What is the problem then?

Comment: yes, it always called 13 times.but the problem is after 6, the pages are all same as page1.